# Bash - How to format file in orderly manner?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, delimiter

This is driving me nuts...

I have a file `BookDB.txt` which stores data in the following format :

```
Python for dummies:Pauline:10.45:4:3
Python for dummies:Peter:10.67:0:11
C++ for dummies:Jared Loo:10.56:1:9
```

I want to print an inventory summary of all the books by replacing the (:) delimiter with a (/t) using this command :

`sed 's/:/\t/g' cat BookDB.txt)`

But it simply concatenates all the lines into two lines, such that it looks like this :

```
Title            Author          Price          Qty Avail         Qty Sold       Total Sales
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python for dummies Pauline 10.45 4 3 Python for dummies Peter 10.67 0 11 C++ for dummies Jared Loo 10.56 1 9
Python for dummies Pauline 10.45 4 3 Python for dummies Peter 10.67 0 11 C++ for dummies Jared Loo 10.56 1 9
```

Essentially , I want my output to look like this :

```
Title               Author                Price          Qty Avail.               Qty Sold
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Python for dummies  Pauline                10.45             4                       3
Python for dummies  Peter                  10.67             0                       11
C++ for dummies     Jared Loo              10.56             1                       9
```

Is there a better way to achieve this other than a modification of the sed command listed above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an input like

```
Title:Author:Price:Qty Avail.:Qty Sold
Python for dummies:Pauline:10.45:4:3
Python for dummies:Peter:10.67:0:11
C++ for dummies:Jared Loo:10.56:1:9
```

You can have it formatted with

```
column -t -s : your_file.txt
```

Output:

```
Title               Author     Price  Qty Avail.  Qty Sold
Python for dummies  Pauline    10.45  4           3
Python for dummies  Peter      10.67  0           11
C++ for dummies     Jared Loo  10.56  1           9
```

As for your original document not having the headers, you can simply do

```
(echo 'Title:Author:Price:Qty Avail.:Qty Sold'; cat your_file.txt) | column -t -s :
```

And it would give same output.

You can also add a sed command to insert the horizontal line:

```
< | sed '2s|^|---------------------------------------------------------------\n|'
```

Output:

```
Title               Author     Price  Qty Avail.  Qty Sold
---------------------------------------------------------------
Python for dummies  Pauline    10.45  4           3
Python for dummies  Peter      10.67  0           11
C++ for dummies     Jared Loo  10.56  1           9
```

Similar to sed is:

```
... | awk 'NR == 2 { print "-----..." } 1'

... | awk 'NR == 2 { $0 = "-----..." RS $0 } 1'

... | awk 'NR == 2 { $0 = "-----...\n" $0 } 1'
```

Answer (score 4):

Content of BookDB.txt:

```
Python for dummies:Pauline:10.45:4:3
Python for dummies:Peter:10.67:0:11
C++ for dummies:Jared Loo:10.56:1:9
```

Command:

```
column -ts : <(echo Title:Author:Price:Qty Avail.:Qty Sold) BookDB.txt | sed "1{p;s/./-/g}"
```

Output:

```
Title               Author     Price  Qty Avail.  Qty Sold
----------------------------------------------------------
Python for dummies  Pauline    10.45  4           3
Python for dummies  Peter      10.67  0           11
C++ for dummies     Jared Loo  10.56  1           9
```

Comment: Upvoted for simplicity and elegance of solution. What if I wanted to add a horizontal line between the header and the data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've left out some characters from that `sed` command of yours and that it looks more like `sed 's/:/\t/g' <<<$(cat BookDB.txt)` in reality (though that would be very odd but is the least edited version of what you posted that gets results similar to what you claim you get).

If you just use `sed 's/:/\t/g' BookDB.txt` does it work?